# Overflow in "addi" instruction of MIPS - Examples

Tags: assembly, mips, inline-assembly, bluespec

I realize that **addi** instruction causes an overflow exception. I am currently using Bluespec HDL to simulate processors that cause exceptions and handle them appropriately.

Any way, I am writing some test cases to trigger the overflow exception in particular using the addi command of MIPS.

**Note**: The processors I am testing with are SMIPS based, but I support some MIPS instructions for purposed like Exceptions and Interrupts.

I know my logic for detecting overflow is correct (pseudocode below):

```
if (function == Addi) begin
  if(( a < 0 && b < 0 && result >= 0) || (a >0 && b > 0 && result < 0))
    return True;
  else 
   return False;
end
```

***Question***: What can be an example of an overflow:  I am trying the following:(inline assembly using `__asm__`)

```
 addi $2, $0, 0x7fff
 addi $3, $2, 0x000f
```

and this is not throwing an exception. And if I try this:

```
 addi $2, $0, 0x7fffffff
 addi $3, $2, 0x0000000f
```

I get an assembler error because the immediate has to be 16-bits. How can I get an overflow from andi? can you give me good examples... Do I need to use other instructions to fill up high order bits?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sequence does not cause an overflow exception because the registers are 32-bit.  32767 + 15 = 32782, well within 32 bits.

You can't load large immediates in a single instruction in MIPS.  First use a LUI instruction to load the top 16 bits in, then ADDI (or ORI, or XORI)  in the lower 16 bits.

You could also LW to bring a 32-bit value in from memory.

Comment: I am not very familiar with assembly, so can you please put an example. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how you can be using HDL, simulating processors, and writing code that implements overflow detection but you can't understand assembly instructions.

Comment: Well. I am a part of the project of testing processor architecture. Bluespec is very high level of thinking where you only define rules to  pipeline the processor without need to understand assembly details. Nevermind my previous question, I understand what you mean.

Comment: Also, this is support for a class. I took this class earlier and now I am trying to get support for exception for the processor working with the professor. the class dives into bluespec and processor design with no intro to assembly at all! hehe

Comment: Thank You. I just opened that to check the lui instruction.